Uncrustify - which configuration parameters are used to adjust method chaining styling?
For example:
QString result = QString("Hello %1").arg("World").arg(42);

vs
QString result = QString("Hello %1")
                     .arg("World")
                     .arg(42);

Which parameters in Uncrustify can be used to adjust the styling of method chaining?
